# Randomization test and comparisons of many to 1

Tags: multiple-comparisons, permutation-test

I have about 80 different groups, each with 3 replicates which I would like to compare against a control having always a value of 1. As I have a low number of replicates and many groups having 2 replicates with 0 values, I would rather do a randomization test than pairwise mann-u test. However, I'm not sure wether I can resample across all groups to then calculate the difference with 1 (the value of the control) or if this would only tell me the probability of having at least one group that is different from one.

So far, my strategy was to resample all data points 100000. Then calculate the mean of every third value in all resampled data frames. From each of this I then calculated the difference with respect to one (the control) to get a null distribution of the differences. Finally, I calculated the p-value for each group in my original data set and adjusted by FDR correction.

I am afraid this is not valid, and I then will have to resample each group and the control separatel? However that meansI would have to randomise 6 values, 3 from the group and 3 times 1 from the control, for 80 groups as many times as possible?

Comment: Those tags were edited by someone else...I originally had just multiple comparisons and randomization. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: My apologies. I now see it was @gung, not you, that I should have taken that up with.

Comment: No problem at all, I didn't realise either until you mentioned it. I edited the question a bit, for it to be more clear.